# Does an Activity lose its connection to a service if it goes into the background?

Tags: android

I have an Activity that binds to a service and does operations on it.
Will the Activity lose its connection to the service if it is put into the background and onStop() is called?

When the Activity is restarted, will the connection be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on where you call `unbindService(serviceConnection)`.

`onStop()` does not invalidate an existing bind unless you explicitly call `unbindService()` in `onStop()`.

Also see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html):

> If your client is still bound to a service when your app destroys the client, **destruction causes the client to unbind. It is better practice to unbind the client** as soon as it is done interacting with the service. Doing so allows the idle service to shut down.

Comment: When the Activity is restarted, will the connection be valid?